# How to put text inside a box which already has a plot in R Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a box in R Shiny Dashboard which I am showing a pie chart like this. 
[image]

I want to put a text below the pie chart inside the box.

I am not able how to do it. I tried for fluid row inside but did not work.

```
dashboardBody(
tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
          fluidRow(
            box(
              plotlyOutput("averageplot", height = 650),
              title = "",
              status = "success",
              width = 12,
              fluidRow(textOutput("instructions"))
            ))),
 ))
```

Comment: Can you provide a small running example. Not sure what you mean with inside the box

Comment: Why don't you use the title, subtitle, legend etc. options from the function that you're using to generate your plot. I'm not an expert with Plotly, but you can definitely specify the position of your title to make it below the figure instead of above.